# Como arrancar un sonido cuando la app se pasa en segundo plano?

Tags: ios, swift

Hola se puede reproducir un sonido cuando una app entra en segundo plano o se apaque la pantalla y que pare solo cuando la app vuelva en primer plano sin ningun botton ?

lo que consegui es que arranque automaticamente pero yo quiero solo cuando la app pasa a segundo plano.

este codigo funciona con el emulador pero con el iphone me da este error
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x48)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        do
        {
            let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "song", ofType: "mp3")
            try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath!) as URL)
        }
        catch
        {
            //PROCESS ERROR
        }

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

        do
        {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playback)
        }
        catch
        {

        }

        player.play()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

para hacer lo que quieres debes hacerlo en

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}
```

además debes poner el modo background en las capabilitys de target. pero esto no te asegura que el sonido se ejecute por mucho tiempo pues ios solo asegura en background mode hasta 5 minutos  como maximo, no estoy seguro si puede otorgarte mas tiempo, pero debes tenerlo encuenta.